# What is the Greek word for a non-essential Christian doctrine?

Tags: greek, systematic-theology

What is the Greek word that starts with ***a*** that means nonessential points of faith? It is contrasted with essential dogma, and refers to areas of disagreement which are not critical for Christian faith.

I keep wanting to say *anaphora*, which is obviously incorrect, but I imagine it sounds something like that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiaphora

Comment: Sorry, but this is off-topic here, we don't do translation requests.

Comment: It's not a translation request.  It is a question asking for the word that was taken up into historical Christian theology to designate a particular theological concept.

Comment: @Kris You ought to elaborate on your comment in a formal answer.

Comment: Αδιάφορα (*adiaphora* (plural)). See also “theologoumena.”